# Format data in Google App Engine Differently

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to represent data in Google App Engine's datastore view differently in Python?

For example, if I create a list of `ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)` when I look in the datastore it shows up as: `[datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', 6544293208522752L, _app=u'dev~appstuffhere')]`

Is there any way to change the representation of that to something else? I was working with `__str__`, `__unicode__`, and `__repr__` to see if that is what App Engine looks to for representing this data, but to no avail.

I would prefer to see a list of User Names rather than that `datastore_types.Key.from_path` representation.

Is this possible?

Comment: the datastore viewer is just a convenience really, you'll have to write your own version of it (easy enough) if you want some other behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The datastore viewer doesn't know about your models at all. It purely goes on the entity kinds in the datastore, which are independent of the models themselves.

As Paul says in the comment, if you need a different representation you'll need to build it yourself. To get the usernames from the key properties you'd need to actually fetch the data (remember, the datastore is not a relational db, so there's no such thing as a join):

```
usernames = ', '.join(e.username for e in ndb.get_multi(e.users))
```

Comment: So the datastore is only able to display primitive types and strings then? Is that the issue? I would have to build another way to display the data if I'd like?